# NSURLConnection how to get time remaining information

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a table cell in witch I have to get more information about the file I am downloading, I managed to get all I needed but the time left

Here is an example of what I want to make, I have done everything except the time calculation

Geting file size:

```
fileSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]]/(1024*1024);
```

Downloaded:

```
[_responseData length]/(1024*1024)
```

Speed:

```
 double speed = [_responseData length] / ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - start);
```

where start is also an `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` set in

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

Time Left: ???

[image: managing item download]

Question: How to calculate time left??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine what you need to do is handle the `connection:didReceiveData:` delegate method.

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSDate *lastCheckDate;
@property (atomic, strong) NSDate *startDate;
@property (atomic, strong) NSNumber *fileSize;
@property (atomic, strong) NSNumber *sizeLeft;

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    double dt = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:_lastCheckDate]; // time since last check
    self.lastCheckDate = now;
    double db = [data length]; // bytes received
    double speed = db / dt;
    self.sizeLeft = self.sizeLeft - [NSNumber numberWithDouble:db];
    double averageSpeed = [(_fileSize - _sizeLeft) doubleValue] / [now timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate];
    // time left, based on current speed
    double timeLeftCurrent = [sizeLeft doubleValue] / speed;
    // time left, based on average speed
    double timeLeftAverage = [sizeLeft doubleValue] / averageSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in my calculus i forgot about `sizeLeft` adding this line `self.sizeLeft = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_sizeLeft doubleValue]  - [data length]] ;` to my code, fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

With the help of #kender i managed to answer my question

```
@interface TableViewController ()
{
    NSTimeInterval start; 
}
@property (atomic, strong) NSNumber *sizeLeft;


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
//in this method we get the file size and the start time 
   start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
   NSNumber *fileSize;
  if ([response expectedContentLength] == NSURLResponseUnknownLength) 
  {
    // unknown content size
    fileSize = @0;
  }
  else 
  {
    fileSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];
  }
  self.sizeLeft = fileSize;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    // _responseData is an NSData that i use to get the size i already downloaded
    [_responseData appendData:data]; 
    double speed = [_responseData length] / ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - start);
    self.sizeLeft = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_sizeLeft doubleValue]  - [data length]] ;
    // time based on current speed
    double timeLeft = [_sizeLeft doubleValue] / speed; 
    NSLog(@"time  %.2f",timeLeft);
}
```

Comment: i want to get how much time has passed since i made the web service call..so if time has crossed 3 seconds i will show my activity indicator or progress HUD..I am clearly not able to understand the calculation part..if u could tell me how to calculate time passed, it would be helpful @sken3r.MI